# JAXB elements needed only when method consumes xml/json

Tags: java, xml, rest, jakarta-ee, jaxb

The problem:  I'm trying to avoid some class attribute to be included on `GET` requests as xml element but to be recognized on `POST` request.

The simplified version of my class(only necessary things) :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER)
public class User implements Serializable{

    private String username;
    private String password;

    ...

    @XmlTransient //prevent password to be inserted in XML/JSON on GET requests.
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
}
```

I use `@XmlTransient` in order to prevent password(event though is kept as a hash) to get out on `GET` requests. 
So for a request (let's say) `localhost:8080/app/user/John` it will only be returned (for the sake of simplicity)

```
<user>
    <username>John</username>
</user>
```

but when I try to send some XML/JSON (let's say:) :

```
<user>
    <username>John</username>
    <password>Doe</password>
</user>
```

password get's ignored because of `@XmlTransient` annotation:

```
@POST
@Consumes(value = {"application/xml", "application/json"})
public void insertUser(User user){
    em.persist(user); //ERROR because User#password is NULL
}
```

I would like to know if there is a workaround for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two approaches for solving your problem:

- Check out the [Annox Project](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/ANX/Home). It allows you to have alternative DTO/JAXB mappings.
- Simply use different DTOs for POST and GET

Comment: Isn't any pure JAXB solution? (but still avoiding using 2 DTOs , because I find kinda ugly using one more DTO only for this purpose...)

Comment: As far as I know there isn't a pure JAXB solution for this (except bullet 2)